I can not verify with LinkedIn using CLEAR: We weren't able to verify your identity. Your personal information could not be confirmed
Whenever I try to verify with LinkedIn on clear, I eventually get this,


We weren't able to verify your identity Your personal information could not be confirmed

What's wrong here? I've tried with different email addresses, and phone numbers, and taken multiple pictures of my government ID and selfies. According to LikedIn, "verified members get 60% more profile views on average".

As a premium member, I pay $539.88 (sales tax not included). It's not acceptable to get 40% of that value because CLEAR verification doesn't work.

CLEAR is a scam
I wrote to LinknedIn, and they referred me to CLEAR. I was subsequently informed CLEAR will not work with Google Voice, it also will not work with a cell phone service provided by your employer. The system is just a veneer for Caller ID. From Marlene, a rep that answered me in chat,

At the current time LinkediN and CLEAR uses your mobile carrier to verify your identity. If the caller ID on the device does not match your name it will fail.

There is no way to circumvent this, even as a premium customer LinkedIn can not help.
The CLEAR rep went on to say,

This is the current verification process. they are looking for workarounds but we do not have any as of yet,.

LinkedIn blames CLEAR, and pushes for them to support this. CLEAR blames LinkedIn for not supporting a workaround. It's crazy, and that was enough for me to cancel my subscription to LinkedIn Premium.
